# Parsing a delimited string of key value pair into a dict, while validating each item

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to parse a delimited string of key value pair into a `dict`.

```
# a:1,b:2,c:3
item.split(':') for item in str.split(','))
```

However, there is a possibility when the string contains an incorrect formatted value without a `:`, such as `4` in below example:

```
# a:1,b:2,c:3,4,e:5
```

This causes above code to break with the error `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #3 has length 1; 2 is required`

I want to introduce an `if` condition for such case, so that for if during iteration if any such value is encountered it should be ideally be assigned to a default key such as `x` i.e. `x:4`.

How can i put this condition inline my above code?

Comment: You can't really have a default key because there may be more than one occurrence of the "faulty" element in your list

Comment: How do you determine, whether the faulty element is a key or a value? Ie what should happen on an input like `a:1,b,c:3,4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could construct a default key based on some well-known prefix and append  that with an ever-increasing number. Something like this:

```
def parse_to_dict(s):
    d = dict()
    n = 0
    for t in s.split(','):
        if len(kv := t.split(':')) > 1:
            d[kv[0]] = kv[1]
        else:
            d[f'x_{n}'] = t
            n += 1
    return d

print(parse_to_dict('a:1,b:2,c:3,4,e:5,6'))
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'x_0': '4', 'e': '5', 'x_1': '6'}
```

**Note:**

Input string changed from that in the question to show two erroneous entries in the string and how the output would be affected

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend the default to each item and take the last 2 results of `split`:

```
s = 'a:1,b:2,c:3,4,e:5'

d = dict(('X:' + item).split(':')[-2:] for item in s.split(','))
```

Comment: This works for the data shown in the question (and your code) but what if *s = 'a:1,b:2,c:3,4,e:5,6'*